# swift generic function without parameters

Tags: generics, swift2

How can I specify the subclass in this snippet?
It's not returning anything so the compiler has nothing to infer the type.  Neither can I call root.addSublayers(["a","b"]) without a compiler error.

possible function:

```
func addSublayers(names: [String]? = nil, ofSubType type:???)
func addSublayers<type: CALayer>(names: [String]? = nil)
```

body:

```
{
  for name in (names ?? defaultNames)
  {
     let layer = type() //init a custom subclass of CALayer
     layer.name = name
     self.addSubLayer(layer) 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this question, here is the pattern I am currently using.

```
func foo<T>(type: T.Type) {}
func bar<T>(type: T.Type = String.self) 
{
    foo(type:type)
}
```

This pattern is also used in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
func addSublayers<T: CALayer>(names: [String]? = nil, asdf : T)
{
    for name in names!
    {
        let layer = T() //init a custom subclass of CALayer
        layer.name = name
        self.addSubLayer(layer)
    }
}
```

or this

```
func addSublayers<T: CALayer>(names: [String]? = nil) ->T?
{
    for name in names!
    {
        let layer = T() //init a custom subclass of CALayer
        layer.name = name
        self.addSubLayer(layer)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: I have been going through the xcode release notes. 
It says "Initializers can now be referenced like static methods by referring to .init on a static type reference or type object" Is there a way to leverage this?

Comment: Why would you want to? I don't see how that could help for this case. Unless you alter your custom class so that your init takes string and then you can set the name in the init

Comment: Or extend ca layer and and add your own init. I think that can be done. Will try just now

Comment: because I don't want to add a dummy parameter (asdf) or return an unnecessary nil value? I just want to specify a type and initialise an instance. Like classFromString in obj-c.

Comment: OK so let me get this straight. You want to beable to create any class that has subtype CALayer and then add it to what? a View? How do you know which one you want to create? or are you just making CALayers?

Comment: Just CALayers or subclasses thereof. They are added to another CALayer.
It's just a convenience method. Add these sublayers with these names and set these other properties (color, frame, etc) as well. Sometimes I have to add text layers, sometimes just CALayers, etc.  CALayers have a tree shape. So any layer can de added to any other layer. In my case their behaviour and appearance is slightly different.